# My code is returning the rows repeated instead of just as they are in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, user-interface, tkinter

I have an issue that I can´t see clearly and I ask for help here. I don´t  know why when I run my code the rows print twice instead of just one. I have 5 rows in my database and when I execute the code it returns 10 rows, the first five and then the five repeated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import sqlite3

class fed:

    db_name = 'database.db'

    def __init__(self, window):
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title('ligth')
        self.wind.iconbitmap('doggy.ico')
        self.wind.geometry("500x200")

        self.get_name()

        
   def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return result

    def get_name(self):
        query = 'SELECT * FROM name'
        db_rows = self.run_query(query)
        for row in db_rows:
            print(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    fed(window)
    application = fed(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the class twice, on the 3rd and 2nd to last lines. Remove one of your `fed(window)` calls.